# Using Hibernate Search (Lucene) to query a term with no spaces to match against field value with spaces

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, hibernate-search

I have a `Movie` class with a `name` field. I want to match against movie names that have spaces in it for query terms with no spaces.

For example:  I want the movie with name `Toy Story` to be in the results when the search term is `toystory`.

How to do I write my Hibernate Search DSL Query?

Answer (score 0):

One way of addressing this is actually an index time solution. You could add the movie title as concatenated (w/o spaces) string to the the index using a custom analyzer. This way you would get the functionality you are after for free.

Comment: How do I go about that? Currently I'm using `StandardTokenizerFactory` which tokenizes the words bases on spaces. For `Toy Story` it will create tokens `toy` and `story`. Ideally, I would want to extend the functionality of `StandardTokenizerFactory` to create tokens `toy`, `story`, and `toy story`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add an analyzer to the `Movie` class with a `NGramFilterFactory` and `LowerCaseFilterFactory` filters, then use this analyzer for the name field:

```
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "ngram", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), filters = {
   @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
   @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
       @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "3"), 
       @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "10")
   })
})
public class Movie{

    @Field( analyze = Analyze.YES )
    @Analyzer( definition="ngram" )
    private String name;

    // standard setters and getters go here
}
```

The movie with name `Toy Story` will definitely appear in the results when the search term is `toystory`, just use the next query:

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( Movie.class ).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
  .keyword()
  .onField("name")
  .matching("toystory");
  .createQuery();

org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = 
    fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Movie.class);

List result = hibQuery.list();
```